# How to fix this possibility of denial of service issue?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, security

Following security vulnerability has been reported on our application -

> The call to readLine() at xyz.java line 119 might allow an attacker to
>   crash the program or otherwise make it unavailable to legitimate
>   users.

**Code with vulnerability**
Commented line reported -

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        httpConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer okResponse = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) { //readLine() on this line has been reported
                    okResponse.append(inputLine);
                }
                reader.close();
                return okResponse.toString();
```

The remediation for the same says -

> Validate user input to ensure that it will not cause inappropriate
>   resource utilization.

But, it is not clear what exactly can be validated. Any pointers?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084657/most-robust-way-of-reading-a-file-or-stream-using-java-to-prevent-dos-attacks/17142341#17142341) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412149/how-to-guard-against-resource-exhaustion-and-other-vulnerabilities);

Answer (score 2):

In theory an attacker could send you an unlimited amount of data via the httpConnection. Since you try to consume all of it, it might crash your application (OutOfMemory).

I´d assume you have a certain format and length for the `okResponse` in mind,
so you would be better off checking that.

---

Make sure you read to read the answer from `Subhas` linked by `Luis Muñoz`
 ([Most Robust way of reading a file or stream using Java (to prevent DoS attacks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084657/most-robust-way-of-reading-a-file-or-stream-using-java-to-prevent-dos-attacks/17142341#17142341)),
that has some more implementation details for reading content from a stream.

---

Another issue might be that the attack just keeps the connection open without sending any data. I`d assume there should be a timeout in place to cut the connection at some point, else the thread might be blocked forever.

Edit:
Since you code does not have it explicitly, you also should add a `try ... finally ...` block to make sure that the resources are properly closed.